# Characterizations of positive definiteness of a symmetric matrix of order $2$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $$M=\pmatrix{ a& b \\b&c }$$ be a symmetric matrix.

In my textbook the following result is stated without proof, but I would like to know why it holds, but I cannot figure out what to do to prove it.

Can you give me a hand to understand how to prove this result?

> $$ (M \quad \text{is positive definite}) \iff (det(M)>0 \quad
>  \text{and} \quad a>0 \quad \text{and}\quad  c>0)   \iff (det(M)>0
>  \quad \text{and}\quad  a>0) \iff (det(M)>0 \quad \text{and} \quad
>  c>0). $$

---

I know that a matrix $A \in S_n(\mathbb{R}$  is positive definite iff $X^tAX >0$ for every $X  \in M_{n,1}(\mathbb{R}$ (that is, if the bilinear form $g_A$ associated is positive definite). We have proved the following characterization: $A$ is positive definite iff its eigenvalues are strictly positive. I have also heard of Sylvester's characterization (on the positivity of the determinants of all the submatrices starting from the top left). It would be very instructive if you could show me how to prove the result twice (first using one and then the other characterization).

Comment: What definition of "positive definite" are you using?  Which theorems do you know about positive definite matrices?

Comment: Dear @RobertIsrael, I know that a matrix $A \in S_n(\mathbb{R})$  is positive defined iff $X^tAX >0$ for every $X  \in M_{n,1}(\mathbb{R})$ (that is, if the bilinear form $g_A$ associated is positive defined). We have proved the following characterization: $A$ is positive defined iff its eigenvalues are strictly positive. I have also heard of Sylvester's characterization (on the positivity of the determinants of all the submatrices starting from the top left). It would be very instructive if you could show me how to prove the result twice (first using one and then the other characterization).

Comment: Note that Sylvester's characterization is exactly your 3rd condition, determinant and $a$ positive. By symmetry, it's also determinant and $c$ positive, and, thus, determinant and $a$ and $c$ positive.

Comment: Prof. @GerryMyerson, could you help me prove the result without assuming Sylvester's criterion and using the other characterization of positive definite scalar product (i.e., the one with eigenvalues)?

Comment: The determinant is the product of the eigenvalues, so it's positive if the eigenvalues are both positive. If the eigenvalues are both positive, then $a$ and $c$ can't both be negative, as their sum is the sum of the eigenvlaues; if one of $a,c$ is negative, then the determinant is at most zero.

Comment: Prof. @GerryMyerson, could you clarify why is their sum the sum of the eigenvalues and if one of $a, c$ is negative then the determinant is at most $0$?

Comment: I am confident that you can glance at the formula for the determinant and see that if one of $a,c$ is negative then the determinant is at most zero. For the other, write down the equation whose roots are the eigenvalues, and think about it.

Comment: Thank you, Prof. @GerryMyerson. I see it now. May I ask you if you could answer this other question of mine too: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1233043/self-adjoint-linear-operator-f-a-of-a-scalar-product-g-a ?

Comment: I'll have a look. Meanwhile, let me encourage you to write up and post an answer to the question we have been discussing here.

Comment: I've had a look. Sorry, question doesn't grab me.